# HttpURLConnection and writing file WITH DATA

Tags: java, php, android, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to post a file and data to my server from an Android java script (to my php), it seems I'm pretty much there, but someone PLEASE help me, as I can't seem to format the name/value part (the FILE uploads perfect, but it doesn't send the name value :( )

JAVA:

```
                try{
         int serverResponseCode = 0;
            final String upLoadServerUri = "http://myUrl/upload_file_functions.php";
          String fileName = "/mnt/sdcard/myFile.dat";

            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
            DataOutputStream dos = null;  
            String lineEnd = "\r\n";
            String twoHyphens = "--";
            String boundary = "*****";
            int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
            byte[] buffer;
            int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
            File sourceFile = new File("/mnt/sdcard/myFile.dat"); 


                     // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                       FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                       URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                       // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
                       conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
                       conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                       conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                       conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                       conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                       conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                       conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                       conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                       conn.setRequestProperty("file", fileName); 
                       conn.setRequestProperty("gmail", names[0]);
                       conn.setRequestProperty("phn", phn);

                       dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                       dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
                       dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\";filename=\""
                                                 + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

                       dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);


                       String data = URLEncoder.encode("gmail", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(names[0], "UTF-8");
                       dos.writeBytes(data);



                       dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);




                       // create a buffer of  maximum size
                       bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

                       bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                       buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                       // read file and write it into form...
                       bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

                       while (bytesRead > 0) {

                         dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                         bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                         bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                         bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   

                        }

                       // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                       dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                       dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);





                       dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + names[0] + "\"" + lineEnd);
                       dos.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain"+lineEnd);
                       dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                       dos.writeBytes(names[0]);
                       dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                       dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);


                       //*************************



                       // Responses from the server (code and message)
                       serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                       String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

                       Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : " 
                               + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                       if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                           // it worked !
                       }    




                       //close the streams //
                       fileInputStream.close();
                       dos.flush();
                       dos.close();

        }catch (Exception e){

        }
```

It doesn't work, the FILE sends fine, but I can't get a freaking key/name to send ("gmail:"names[0]) I've also tried:

```
 // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
                           conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
                           conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                           conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                           conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                           conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

                           conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

                           conn.setRequestProperty("gmail", names[0]);
```

dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

```
                           dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                           dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
                           dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\";filename=\""
                                                     + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

                           dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
```

DOESN'T WORK.  I've tried:

```
dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"gmail\";filename=\""+ names[0] + "\"" + lineEnd);
```

Doesn't WORK!  WTF!  I've programmed for years in C++ and python, it's a simple thing!  But I can't figure this out I need help, if you know how to do it PLEASE DO TELL because I've spent two days banging my head against the wall.  I'm not lazy I spent 32+ f'n hours on this please I beg you..

What I WANT to happen: send the file for upload, along with the value (name=gmail value=names[0]; name=phn value=phn), so that the email is associated to the file on my server.
What IS happening: file is uploading fine, but data is not passed (the name/value pairs are not sent)

PHP:

```
    <?php

    set_time_limit(100);


    //need to get email also (gmail address of user)

    //************************************************
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
      {
      echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
      }
    else
      {
      echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
      echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
      echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
      echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }



    function Three(){

    $to =    'me@email.com';
    $subject =   $_POST['phn'] . " " . $_POST['gmail'];
    $bound_text =   "file";
$bound =    "--".$bound_text."\r\n";
$bound_last =   "--".$bound_text."--\r\n";

$headers =  "From: me@email.com\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"
    ."Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$bound_text\"";

$message .= "If you can see this MIME than your client doesn't accept MIME types!\r\n"
    .$bound;

$message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n"
    ."Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n"
    ."hey my <b>good</b> friend here is a picture of regal beagle\r\n"
    .$bound;

$file = file_get_contents("http://myURL/upload/myFile.dat");

$message .= "Content-Type: image/jpg; name=\"myFile.dat\"\r\n"
    ."Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n"
    ."Content-disposition: attachment; file=\"myFile.dat"\r\n"
    ."\r\n"
    .chunk_split(base64_encode($file))
    .$bound_last;
@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

//delete files
$fileArray=array($_FILES["file"]["name"],"myfile.dat","myfile.dat");
foreach($fileArray as $value){
 if(file_exists($value)){
  unlink($value);
 }
}

chdir($old_path);
}

function runAll(){
 One();
 Two();
 Three();
}
runAll();
$randx=null;
unset($randx);


?>
```

PLEASE HELP! The JAVA is not sending the name='gmail' value=names[0], nor the name='phn' value=phn ..

Comment: Have you checked (with a sniffer like Wireshark) that Java is effectively not sending the property? Anyway, it has been a time since I used something like that, but passing your data (filename and the gmail data) as properties is strange and maybe the server is just filtering them out as "non-standard". Since it is a "multipart" message, I would try writting them in the body, in a different part(again, it has been a while since I have touched this).

Comment: You'd want to set the entity as multipart mime. Google that -- you're bound to find numerous examples, here and elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you:)  I was unable to get the Mimetype libraries to work in Eclipse..

Answer (score 1):

You should really read up on a few things: HTTP (and the distinction between request header fields and the post body), and the structure of a multipart/form-data post body.

This:

```
         conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
         conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
         conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
         conn.setRequestProperty("file", fileName); 
         conn.setRequestProperty("gmail", names[0]);
         conn.setRequestProperty("phn", phn);
```

sends a few **request headers**, which is fine for `Content-Type` and such, but not necessarily for the data you're posting. Lose all but the `Content-Type` line.

This:

```
         dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
```

is the right way to start a post field (or file), you should output this for every posted field.

This:

```
         dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
```

signals that all fields have been sent, you should send this as the very last line.

Either use something like Wireshark to see what your final request looks like (either side will do; the device doing the request or the server handling it), or log your request so you can inspect it, and see if it is perfect. It has to be nearly perfect for the webserver/php to process it correctly.

Comment: So it should look like what?

Comment: [code]conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\";filename=\""+ fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + names[0] + "\"" + lineEnd);dos.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain"+lineEnd);
dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
dos.writeBytes(names[0]);
dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);[/code]

Comment: I've tried can you please send the code of what you mean?  Lose all but the Content-Type?  But it works fine for the file upload.  Please post some code showing what you mean.

Comment: Please put some effort in this instead of just requesting code. Update the question with your new code and we'll take it from there.

Comment: I've updated it, plus a few of the 13 different solutions I've tried but haven't worked..  is this really a case of it not being possible?  I mean, every programming language can do this (Python; C++; ..), surely people must upload files along with string data (description etc..) Why is this so hard???

Comment: It is not hard. It is hard for you, because you don't read well. I clearly said that `setRequestProperty` sends request headers, which are not used to transmit form data. You **have** to try to understand what's going on, and once you put enough effort in, you'll see that it is not really hard.

Comment: So what part of **Lose all but the Content-Type line.** did you not understand?

Comment: Yes, I did what you said, got rid of  conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
         conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");        conn.setRequestProperty("file", fileName); 
         conn.setRequestProperty("gmail", names[0]);
         conn.setRequestProperty("phn", phn);

Comment: That made no difference.  See, the file is uploading fine, I'm proud to have figured that out at least, but how do I add a name/key pair?  And please guide me to WHAT TO READ, as I don't know where there is any documentation..

Comment: conn.setRequestProperty("file", fileName); is still in your code sample. Please update the question to your current status. You need to read what I posted, in particular the part about outputting `dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);` for every posted field. I don't see you doing this in your code.

Comment: Nobody can help you if you don't share your progress. We can't read thoughts nor see what you are trying, unless you show it.

Comment: Sorry but I thought this is where people go to get help and learn together.  I code for servers a little, Android a lot, games a lot, but I haven't done much with http data, and shame on me I suppose.  If you can't help me, then I guess this QUESTION will just go unanswered.  I'm now just appending the filename to that of my data, since you won't give a bro a hand.  I have NO manual, you've not directed me anywhere to LEARN.  You are a tease and it's not appreciated.  Peace

Comment: Hi Dave, you might have noticed that nobody feels like answering your "question". This is probably because your "question" is a "gimme teh code" kind of question. If you feel differently, that's fine by me. But still you will have to acknowledge that most real questions on SO do get a few good answers within minutes. So instead of putting the blame on me, try to look at yourself first, and at least appreciate the effort I'm putting in to writing all this down for you.

Comment: Where to look: use google to learn about the structure of HTTP requests (headers+body) and multipart/form-data requests in particular.

Comment: You will see that there is such a thing as an HTTP request header (which HTTPURLConnection calls a RequestProperty; don't ask me why) which contains stuff *about the request*, i.e. not the form fields/files posted, but "metadata" giving the Content-Type for example. You don't need to put the form data in there, so **lose all but the Content-Type line from the setRequestProperty() bunch of code**.

Comment: Furthermore, you will see that a multipart/form-data request has all fields (files + form fields) separated by "--boundary" strings, with the last field terminated by "--boundary--". You are sending "--boundary--" *twice*, which is not good. For every field you are sending, you need a part saying "--boundary", "Content-Disposition: form-data; name='somefield'", "Content-Type: text/plain", followed by a newline and the actual value for 'somefield'.

Comment: But I said all this before, and it has been explained thousands of times all over the web. You will have to write your own code. If you want to have somebody write it for you, hire someone. But if you do decide to fix your own code, **update the question with your last code, and remove anything irrelevant** so I can see what you've done and give a few pointers to help you fix your own code.

Comment: ... and my next challenge is to get it all running off the main Activity, in a service, once a day, in the background.. yikes :P

Answer (score 1):

Well, I never figured out how to send a simple string parameter with the file upload, but my workaround was to simply append the filename of the upload file to INCLUDE the string I wanted to send:

```
 @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences); 




    try{

            Account[] accounts=AccountManager.get(this).getAccountsByType("com.google");
            String myEmailid=accounts[0].toString(); Log.d("My email id that i want", myEmailid);

            String[] names = new String[accounts.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
                names[i] = accounts[i].name;
            }
            // THE DEVICE EMAIL ADDRESS WAS ONE OF THE DATA STRINGS I NEEDED TO SEND


            File from = new File("/mnt/sdcard/","UPLOADFILE.DAT");
            File to = new File("/mnt/sdcard/",names[0]+".BLOCK1."+"DATASTRING2"+".BLOCK2");
            from.renameTo(to);

            // DATASTRING2 is the SECOND piece of DATA I wanted to send
            // SO YOU SEE I'M SIMPLY APPENDING THE UPLOAD FILE WITH THE DATA I WANT
            // TO SEND WITH THE FILE, AND WHEN MY SERVER RECEIVES IT, I USE SOME SIMPLE
            // PHP TO PARSE OUT WHATS BEFORE .BLOCK1. AND THEN .BLOCK2

         StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
         StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 

        try{
         int serverResponseCode = 0;
            final String upLoadServerUri = "http://MYURL/upload_file_functions.php";
          String fileName = "/mnt/sdcard/"+names[0]+".BLOCK1."+"DATASTRING2"+".BLOCK2";

            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
            DataOutputStream dos = null;  
            String lineEnd = "\r\n";
            String twoHyphens = "--";
            String boundary = "*****";
            int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
            byte[] buffer;
            int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
            File sourceFile = new File("/mnt/sdcard/"+names[0]+".BLOCK1."+"DATASTRING2"+".BLOCK2""); 


                     // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                       FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                       URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                       // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
                       conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
                       conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                       conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                       conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                       conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                       conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                       dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                       dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
                       dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\";filename=\""+ fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
                       dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                       // create a buffer of  maximum size
                       bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 
                       bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                       buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                       // read file and write it into form...
                       bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

                       while (bytesRead > 0) {
                         dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                         bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                         bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                         bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   
                        }

                       // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                       dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                       dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);


                      // Responses from the server (code and message)
                       serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                       String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

                       Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : " 
                               + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                       //close the streams //
                       fileInputStream.close();
                       dos.flush();
                       dos.close();

        }catch (Exception e){

        }


    }catch (Exception e){


    }

}
```

Thanks for the help!  (THICK WITH SARCASM..) Seriously, I have to code in python, C++, java, PHP, on linux, Android, iPhone, Windows, MAC and Ubuntu... my work has me building Triple-Boot OS box's, building apps in Android and iPhone to support my business needs, and thus I must know PHP html and the like, needed to configure my own server because I needed email-notification services, so I needed to run my own email server (Exim on Ubuntu Server), and I've had to learn all this in the past 6 months.

Forgive me if my code's not pretty, but I don't have the luxury of time, as I'm going INSANE trying to keep up in the land of AI, Object recognition, and trying to make the rent (though I've learned enough to do so..)
DC:)